# How to only SELECT rows with non-zero and non-null columns efficiently in Big Query?

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am having a table with large number of columns in Big Query.

The table has lot of rows with some column values as 0/0.0 and null.

For example

```
Row A      B    C     D     E   F
1   "abc"  0   null  "xyz"  0   0.0
2   "bcd"  1    5    "wed"  4   65.5
```

I need to select only those rows which have non zero Integer, Float and non NULL values. Basically, I need just Row 2 in the above table

I know I can do this by using this query for each of the columns

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (B IS NOT NULL AND B is !=0) AND
.
.
.
```

But I have lot of columns and writing query like this for each of the columns would be difficult. Is there any better approach to handle this?

Comment: Not really.  An extended `where` clause is probably the simplest way to implement this logic.

Comment: Have you considered adding a PERSISTED COMPUTED COLUMN to you TABLE, you can name it IsAllZerosOrNull and use this column on your WHERE conditions (WHERE IsAllZerosOrNull = 0). You can also put this column inside an Index to get faster result

Answer (score 2):

Below example for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT "abc" a, 0 b, NULL c, "xyz" d, 0 e, 0.0 f UNION ALL
  SELECT "bcd", 1, 5, "wed", 4, 65.5 
)
SELECT *
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
WHERE NOT REGEXP_CONTAINS(TO_JSON_STRING(t), r':0[,}]|null[,}]')
```

with output

```
Row a   b   c   d   e   f    
1   bcd 1   5   wed 4   65.5
```