# Google Big Query: how to filter output to show only rows that have at least 1 non-zero value?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, where-clause

I am working on a dataset that looks like this:

[image]

As a result of this query:

```
SELECT "campaign_1" campaign_name, 0 clicks, 5 impressions, 1000 cost UNION ALL
SELECT "campaign_2", 1, 5, 0 UNION ALL
SELECT "campaign_3", 0, 0, 0
```

My goal is to show all rows in this table that have at least 1 non-zero value. In other words, my desired output is:

[image]

To solve my own problem, I tried to use a big WHERE clause including names of every column, listing each in the following format: `WHERE column_1 != 0 AND column_2 != 0 ...`. This didn't work, because it also eliminated first 2 rows, since they also contain 0s.

I have searched StackOverflow for existing answers to this problem, and while I found a solution to a similar problem by Mikhail Berlyant [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57822709/how-to-only-select-rows-with-non-zero-and-non-null-columns-efficiently-in-big-qu), this particular solution does not apply to this scenario. Therefore, I posted this as a new question.

Thank you in advance for sharing your knowledge and your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the values cannot be negative or `null` (as shown in your sample data), you can do:

```
where column_1 + column_2 + ... > 0
```

Or you can use `greatest()`:

```
where greatest(column_1, column_2, ...) > 0
```

Comment: This worked well and it also taught me the new function - greatest() - which I have not used or seen before. Thank you! Please consider upvoting this question if you find it beneficial for SO community.

Answer (score 1):

In case if for some reason you want to reuse solution from post you referenced in your question - you can use below variation of it

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(TO_JSON_STRING(t), r':[^0][,}]')
```

with output (if to apply to sample data from your question)

[image]

The potential benefit for you using this solution is in case if you have more than just 3-5 columns/metrics - in this case you don't need to call them out explicitly in your query

Also note: above assumes that campaign's name has more than one character

Comment: Thank you for your input! Can you please recommend a source for me to learn REGEXP syntax? As of now, GMB's answer is more clear to me because it is simple and I can read it, but I can't read your REGEXP because I didn't study it before. However, based on your description, I think your solution may be better. Happy to upvote and select this as accepted answer if after studying REGEXP I will realize your solution is better. So far, I get 2 different solutions using your and GMB's code, and studying REGEXP will help me understand why. Thank you!

Comment: you can upvote answer anyway - as looks like it helped you find another interesting approach even if it is not the best in this particular use case  - this is really up to you. as of sources - start with [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_contains) and then look in SO for regex tag :o)

Comment: You are right, your way did offer me an interesting new solution. I will review documentation and study REGEX EXP. I will then select your answer as accepted if it will be a better approach for me. Please consider upvoting my question if you deem it valuable for SO community to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Would you not in this case use an `OR` operator to between all your conditions.  In that scenario you would still eliminate campaign_3 while retaining 1 and 2.

`WHERE column_1 != 0 OR column_2 != 0` .... But what GMB outlined seems much simpler and less prone to error.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Can you please provide the code to show what you mean exactly? I selected GMB's answer as the accepted one, but happy to upvote your solution too if it will work.